# classic keyboard in modern laptop?

Tags: laptop, keyboards

Does anyone know a modern laptop which is equipped with the classic keyboard? Similar to those from old ThinkPad laptops, e.g. T420 or T500?

My problem is that my Thinkpad T420 is at the winter of its live and probably this or next year I would need a new machine and I just hate the chiclet keyboards.

Comment: Do you have a budget? Internal hardware requirements aside from keyboard switch style?

Comment: Money is not a question here. I'm a typist and I work 90% of my time with my laptop so I need a functional, ergonomic keyboard - that gives me my old thinkpad. Rest of the hardware is relevant, except of one, the screen size should be 14"+ & resolution fHD or around it.